# Get supported languages QuickPick

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm writing a VSCode extensions and I would like to be able to let the user select a language from the known programming languages in VSCode (same as 'Select Language Mode' QuickPick).

How can this be achieved?

[image: Select Language Mode]

--- 2/19/2019 ---

Still struggling with this.
Is it possible at all?